# Changing webkit transition duration using javascript on iPad?

Tags: javascript, ipad, webkit, css-transitions

I am using web-kit transitions in an iPad app. They work great. But I was wondering what I would do to change the values of my transition using javascript.

```
#container {
            -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
            -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;       
        }
```

What I would like to do:

```
<script>
    function func() {
        document.getElemeentById('container').transition.duration = 500;

   }
</script>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can be done with:

```
document.getElementById('container').style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = '500s';
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/z3bKD/2/.

Answer (score 1):

Jakub's answer was good, but to update it, you can now set the transition duration directly as the `transitionDuration` property on an element's `style`. Tested and working on iOS Safari, OSX Safari, Chrome and Firefox. e.g.

```
document.getElementById('container').style.transitionDuration = '500s';
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jkoudys/xa2oo1us/